# Cache a StreamedResponse?

Tags: php, caching, drupal-8

My end goal is to cache an expensive operation and large output that I currently serve through a StreamingResponse.  How?  Please bear in mind that I'm relatively new to Drupal.

I've created an API endpoint, that generates output on demand.  The output size can vary -- enough so that I want to stream the response -- and can change semi-regularly (say once or twice a day).

Streaming is basically a freebie (thanks Drupal/Symfony!) and I have that working:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;

...

public function GETLargishOutputEndpoint ( ) {
  $response = new StreamedResponse(function() {
    # Generate output in streaming fashion, say a large Lorem Ipsum
    while ( $someCriterion ) {
      echo "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ...";
      $someCriterion = ... # assign true or false
    }
  });

  $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'x-application/lorem+ipsum');

  return $response;
}
```

The output is expensive enough to create that I'd like to incur the cost only once per change (if for no other reason than user experience and delayed download time).  But how, with a StreamedResponse?  Google has not been my friend so far.

I'm willing to accept that I have to implement this manually and that I can't utilize [CacheableResponseInterface](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/response/cacheable-response-interface), but am hoping I'm missing something (non)obvious.

(This is on Drupal 8.5)

Answer (score 0):

I have not figured out how to work with both a StreamedResponse and pulling from cache.  For our current scenario, it's a win to pull from cache; this will not be feasible if the generated output gets too large.

Meanwhile, the working code boils down to the basic "pull from cache" paradigm:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;

...

public function GETLargishOutputEndpoint ( int $nid ) {
  $cid = "some_unique:$nid";

  if ( ! ($cache = \Drupal::cache()->get( $cid ) ) {
    $response = new Response( $cache->data );
  }
  else {
    $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load( $nid );
    $cache_tags = $node->getCacheTags();

    $data = SomeExpensiveOperation( $nid );

    \Drupal::cache()->set($cid, $data, \Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheBackendInterface::CACHE_PERMANENT, $cache_tags);

    $response = new Response( $data );
  }

  return $response;
}
```